# Java mail problem attaching files with Long filenames more than 60 characters

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, attachment

My application sends out mail with attachment. Problem arises if the attached filename is more than 60 characters.  Because in that scenario, the filename is automatically trimmed to 60 characters when the recipient sees the mail in outlook.  When I printed the headers in my java code I can see that the filename (`1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.txt`) has been split into multiple parameters, slicing at the 60th character.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii; ^M
        name*0=123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890; ^M
        name*1=1234567890.txt^M
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit^M
Content-Disposition: attachment; ^M
        filename*0=123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890; ^M
        filename*1=1234567890.txt^M
```

Somehow Outlook picks up only filename*0

I came across a post (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html) that said setting this property to false mail.mime.foldtext will help, but to no avail.
Any pointers on this will be of great help

My java code snippet

```
MimeAttachment attachment = attachments[i];
MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new MimeAttachmentDataSource(attachment)));
bodyPart.setFileName(attachment.getFilename());
bodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
```

much thanks

Comment: Could you check with setting this parameter to false:
`mail.mime.splitlongparameters`.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't help. I used                System.setProperty("mail.mime.splitlongparameters", "false");

Comment: Is there a specific location in the code I should add it?

Comment: You can check at the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196491/spring-mimemessagehelper-attachment-filename-encoding

Comment: The system property `mail.mime.splitlongparameters` should have the expected effect. However, it is evaluated only once by javamail/Jakarta Mail upon loading class [`ParameterList`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/342d86b928b7d390e879dc2d47eb897879946849/mail/src/main/java/jakarta/mail/internet/ParameterList.java#L132). As this class is referenced by other parts of javamail, it might be loaded earlier then expected so that setting the property via `System.setProperty()` might only happen afterwards.

Comment: Also, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344141/8362098