# Outlook: problem with attachment in EML file generated by JavaMail

Tags: email, outlook, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have a problem opening emails with Outlook.

I am creating emails with JavaMail/JakartaMail API (version 1.6.x) in the rfc-email-format with the ending `*.eml`. Occasionally I have attachments with very long attachment names. JavaMail conforms to [RFC2231 section 3: Parameter Value Continuations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231#section-3) and splits long filenames (as far as my few oservations can tell) after 60 characters.

So a short attachment name looks something like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename=short-filename.txt
```

and a long filename looks something like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename*0=this-is-a-filename-with-more-than-60-characters-which-is-ult;
    filename*1=imately-the-source-of-this-question.txt
```

Now if I open this `*.eml` file in Outlook, the first filename is displayed as is, but for the second attachment the name is something like *unknown attachment 00004.txt*.

If I open the email in Mozilla Thunderbird, everything works like a charm.

So I wonder if this is a bug in Outlook that does not implement parameter value continuation of RFC2231?

Or maybe this is just a bug in JavaMail implementation and Thunderbird is as robust as it does not care about this potential bug in JavaMail?

And most importantly, is there a better solution that implementing email generation and all affected RFCs myself, to get this to work in Oultook?

Comment: Neither Outlook nor Thunderbird is particularly RFC-conformant when you get down to it. A possible workaround is to zip the attachment and store the proper long filename inside the archive, and give it a short and nondescript name for the benefit of Outlook victims.

Comment: The lack of quotes around the `filename=` value is RFC-conformant but possibly confusing for Outlook. I have no idea whether adding quotes would help any, or even break the RFC spec, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: I just added quotes to the file. Sadly it had no effect. But it was a good suggestion @tripleee :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in an older SO question [Seems like JavaMail's MimeBodyPart.setFileName inserts a line break in the email message and causes the filename to show up as invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344141).

Setting `mail.mime.splitlongparameters` to `false` works perfectly for me.